# Function in .bash_aliases not accepting full command string

Tags: bash, function, alias

I have a loop function in .bash_aliases to help me quickly monitor certain commands.

```
loop()
{
 while sleep 1;
  do $@;
 done
}
```

However, I cannot get this command to work:

```
# loop mysql vb -e 'select count(*) from postparsed;'

# loop mysql vb -e "select count(*) from postparsed;"

# loop "mysql vb -e 'select count(*) from postparsed;'"
```

All of these return a mysql invalid command line parameter error, because the entire string isn't getting passed to mysql.

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
> using readline 5.2 Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB
> Corporation Ab and others.
>
> Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

I also confirmed with this:

> ## loop echo mysql vb -e 'select count(*) from postparsed;'
>
> mysql vb -e select count(*) from postparsed;
>
> mysql vb -e select count(*) from postparsed;

Looks fine to me.

What am I missing?  Why is the loop() function not processing my mysql command correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Always use `"$@"`, not unquoted `$@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell interprets the quotes, so the script doesn't see what you entered at the command line. What you need is

```
loop mysql vb -e 'select count(*) from postparsed;'
```

At the same time, though, you need to change the script to keep the whole SQL command as one word. Just double quote the parameter array to achieve this:

```
do "$@"
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, thank you